# decorating base class methods in python

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, decorator, python-decorators

I have a python class, for example:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Drawing(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def draw(self):
        pass


class Sketch(Drawing):

    # overriding abstract method
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing a sketch")



# Driver code
R = Sketch()
R.draw()
```

*here is the goal of what he wants to achieve:*

Create an abstract Drawing class that implements the draw () interface. Develop a child class of the Drawing class in the form of the Sketch class. Make the draw () interface more specific with the message Sketch drawn.

***problem:***
but also I want to create decorators that change the sketch style (eg "pencil sketch drawn" or "pen sketch drawn").
my question is how can i do it right, is what i am doing in the code below correct?

```
 class Drawing(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def draw(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def drawPencil(self):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def drawPen(self):
        pass

class Sketch(Drawing):
    
   
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing a sketch")

    def drawPencil(self):
        print("Drawing with pencil")

    def drawPen(self):
        print("Drawing with pen")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take as base class

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class IDrawing(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def draw():
        pass

class Sketch(IDrawing):
    #override
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing a sketch")

r = Sketch()
r.draw()
#Drawing a sketch
```

You use `@staticmethod` if this abstractmethod doesn't need any class-intern attribute.
You use otherwise `@classmethod` and give as first argument `cls` (since abstractmethod cannot have `self` to refer to an instance).
It works without `@staticmethod`, too ...

Now using your `print` functions, I would do and define decorators like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class IDrawing(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def draw():
        pass

def pen(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("with a pen")
    return new_func

def pencil(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("with a pencil")
    return new_func

class Sketch(IDrawing):
    #override
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing a sketch")
    
    @pen
    def drawPen(self):
        print("Drawing ", end="")
    
    @pencil
    def drawPencil(self):
        print("Drawing ", end="")

r = Sketch()
r.draw()
r.drawPen()
r.drawPencil()
#Drawing a sketch
#Drawing with a pen
#Drawing with a pencil
```

I personally prefer however functions which return strings and use the `print` command when calling them.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class IDrawing(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def draw():
        pass

def pen(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) + " with a pen"
    return new_func

def pencil(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs) + " with a pencil"
    return new_func

class Sketch(IDrawing):
    #override
    def draw(self):
        return "Drawing a sketch"
    
    @pen
    def drawPen(self):
        return "Drawing"
    
    @pencil
    def drawPencil(self):
        return "Drawing"

r = Sketch()
print(r.draw())
print(r.drawPen())
print(r.drawPencil())
#Drawing a sketch
#Drawing with a pen
#Drawing with a pencil
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want different derived classes which do their drawing differently?

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Drawing(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def draw(self):
        pass

class Sketch(Drawing):
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing a sketch")

class PencilSketch(Drawing):
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing with pencil")

class PenSketch(Drawing):
    def draw(self):
        print("Drawing with pen")

drawObjs = [Sketch(), PencilSketch(), PenSketch()]
for obj in drawObjs:
    obj.draw()
```

Output:

```
Drawing a sketch
Drawing with pencil
Drawing with pen
```